# Why has my reputation score suddenly gone up?

Tags: support

I just notice that my reputation score suddenly got bumped up by a sizeable number.

I don't see any count on reputation button on top right, neither do I see anything under and Reputation tab on my Activity page. Normally I can look at recent reputation badge and see a daily count. This isn't showing as a change in the last week.

What caused my increase in reputation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers:

> We’re changing the reputation earned from getting a question upvote to ten points, making it equal to the reputation earned from an upvote to an answer.
>
> We’re recalculating reputation for every Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange individual based on this change. Every question upvote earned in the past will earn a value of ten reputation points retroactively.